# Debugging an SEHException (InteropServices exception) in visual studio C# - System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, interop

I am new to C# and visual studio. And I have an multi-threaded C# application that I am trying to run. It throws following exception during runtime:

```
'MyApplication.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: f96e1533-845f-4531-9e22-611835cc0abc): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

'MyApplication.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: f96e1533-845f-4531-9e22-611835cc0abc): Loaded 'D:\workspace\Apps\Branches\X\Applications\MyApplication\bin\Debug\GGT.Games.dll'. Symbols loaded.
System.Transactions Critical: 0 : 'MyApplication.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: f96e1533-845f-4531-9e22-611835cc0abc): Loaded 'C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Critical"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/Unhandled</TraceIdentifier><Description>Unhandled exception</Description><AppDomain>MyApp</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>External component has thrown an exception.</Message><StackTrace>   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CloseHandle(IntPtr handle)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle.ReleaseHandle()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.
at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.CloseHandle(IntPtr handle)
at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle.ReleaseHandle()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.InternalFinalize()
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.Finalize()</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord>
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in mscorlib.dll External component has thrown an exception.
```

If I am not wrong, this exception is thrown by `GC Finalizer` while trying to dispose some handle.

How can I know what handle it is ? This exception trace doesn't help much without telling me what part of the code allocated it.

Is there a way to know the handle and what part of the code allocated it ?

Thanks.

Comment: mmm.. at first glance I'm not completely sure about the questions you ask.. I would say this part has thrown an exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException. I will edit your question.. accept it if you like it

Comment: Failure to property release a SafeHandle is a pretty serious problem.  It is the antipode of "safe", the runtime should yell loudly.  The most obvious possible reason, without any code to look at, is that the code you are trying to run is not in fact thread-safe.  It rarely is.   You can't get a good stack trace, apparently you are not using Dispose() either.  Don't plan to get anything done next week, ask an experienced programmer to review your code.  Use a telephone if he doesn't live in the next cubicle.

Comment: @HansPassant Don’t see the point of your comment. I am aware of the reason behind this exception, especially after few links provided. What I was looking for specifically was whether there was some option I need to turn on to get more info during runtime.  Anyways I will figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: @Monku Did you managed to improve your visibility ? I'm facing similar problem (just the `SEHException`), and I'm hacing hard time to find out the root problem. (I own all the code).

Comment: @Soleil In my case, I was running debug build of my application with release build of the reference libraries from another team. I switched to release build and everything worked fine. Probably you have something else going on. I am sorry I have no idea about how to debug this.